# How to transliterate 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation to Ukrainian?

Tags: фонетика, transliteration

I am working on an art project that I would like to collect the hundreds of different transliterations of 「中文」 zhōng wén in Mandarin Chinese. (Pronunciation available here: [https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/中文](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87))

How can I transliterate zhōng wén in Ukrainian? (For example, "zhong wen" would be the closest pronunciation in English.)

Comment: Already asked on Russian.SE: http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/14185/551

Comment: Try this. It's a new Chinese to Ukraninian transliteration system.
http://www.epochtimes.com.ua/china/chinese-characters/znayomtesya-nova-ukrayinska-sistema-transkriptsiyi-kitayskikh-ieroglifiv-107641.html

Comment: @Artemix, it's actually stated within text of the question that author asks it for all languages (not only Russian and Ukrainian).

Answer (score 14):

The standards of Ukrainian language actually follow **the Palladius system** (Ukr: Система Палладія). Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillization_of_Chinese),

> The Cyrillization of Chinese is effected using the Palladius system for transcribing Chinese characters into the Cyrillic alphabet.

There are several fine nuances that mostly reflect differences between Russian and Ukrainian, one may find the full list in the Wikipedia page for [Система Палладія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F).

Also, the above page contains a complete list of corresponding syllables between 拼音 and the Ukrainian Cyrillic.

Hence, 中文 would be `чжунвень`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56395/discussion-on-answer-by-bytebuster-how-to-transliterate--in-mandarin-pronuncia).

Comment: 中文 is one word, therefore its Palladius rendering should be written as one word, too, `чжунвень`.

Answer (score 6):

*Just for notice: unfortunately, I don't know Chinese.*

---

Long time it was [**the Palladius system**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F) which is for **Russian** but was just copied to Ukrainian. It was also named as *adaptation by Kirnosova*.

**чжун вень**

Later it was [accepted](//nas.gov.ua/UA/Messages/Pages/View.aspx?MessageID=6303) by [NANU](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8) which is a goverment structure and with really [a strange moves](//ueartemis.livejournal.com/29118.html).

---

But hereʼs problem that many translations based on Russian arenʼt good for Ukrainian because of sensitivity different of phonetic between Ukrainian and Russian. So here were debates or seminars on [high level](//facebook.com/safranbook/posts/1000564633468289) about more correctly transliteration for **Ukrainian**. In result some publishers use [**the Kirnosova-Tsisar system**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97%E2%80%94%D0%A6%D1%96%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80).

**джон вень**

Comment: The funny thing is, while **в** is /v/ in Russian, it is /w/ in Ukrainian. So the Palladius Cyrillization of Chinese suits Ukrainian pronunciation more than it does Russian in some cases.